# How do I check if one square is overlapping another in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I have a little program that goes like this:

Whenever somebody presses space, a blue square appears. The blue square shouldn't overlap with any other blue square.

But the function that is checking the overlap is not working! Can somebody please help?

```
window.onload = function() { //Starts the program when the page is loaded.

  var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");
  var background = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var squareDisplay = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  var xAndYvaluesOfSquares = [];

  //Makes a randint() function.
  function randint(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  function checkForOccupiedAlready(testXPos, testYPos) {
    if (xAndYvaluesOfSquares.length != 0) {
      for (valuePair in xAndYvaluesOfSquares) {
        if (
          ( valuePair[0] + 20 ) < testXPos && 
          ( valuePair[0] - 20 ) > testXPos && 
          ( valuePair[1] + 20 ) < testYPos && 
          ( valuePair[1] - 20 ) > testYPos){ //If in the same area
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  //Makes a new square
  function makeNewsquare() {

    var checkingIfRepeatCords = true;
    //DO loop that checks if there is a repeat.
    do {
      //Makes the square x/y positions
      var squareRandomXPos = randint(50, canvas.width - 50);
      var squareRandomYPos = randint(50, canvas.height - 50);

      //Tests if that area is already occupied
      if (checkForOccupiedAlready(squareRandomXPos, squareRandomYPos) == true) {
        xAndYvaluesOfSquares.push([squareRandomXPos, squareRandomYPos]);
        checkingIfRepeatCords = false;
      }
    }
    while (checkingIfRepeatCords == true);
  }

  function resetBoard() {
    for (i = 0; i < xAndYvaluesOfSquares.length; i++) {
      var XYvalue = xAndYvaluesOfSquares[i];

      squareDisplay.beginPath();
      squareDisplay.fillStyle = "rgb(50, 50, 125)";
      squareDisplay.rect(XYvalue[0], XYvalue[1], 50, 50);
      squareDisplay.fill();

    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) { //Space key
      makeNewsquare();
      resetBoard();
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether one rectangle overlaps another rectangle by checking their edges;  if we have two rectangles `a` and `b`, and if the two rectangles aren't intersecting, then evaluate the following four statements:

- `a`'s left edge is to the right of `b`'s right edge
- `a`'s top edge is beneath `b`'s bottom edge
- `a`'s right edge is to the left of `b`'s left edge
- `a`'s bottom edge is above `b`'s top edge.

If even one of the above statements is true, then the two rectangles do not overlap.  Otherwise, they do overlap.

In pseudocode, you can represent that logic like this:

```
if (a.left >= b.right || a.top >= b.bottom || 
    a.right <= b.left || a.bottom <= b.top)
{
    // no overlap
}
else
{
    // overlap
}
```

**Caveat #1**: In this pseudocode, I'm interpreting two rectangles with opposite edges on the same point as *not* overlapping.  If you want those rectangles to count as overlapping, use regular `<` and `>` tests, instead of `<=` and `>=`.

**Caveat #2**: In this pseudocode, I'm assuming that you're using a coordinate system in which positive 'y' extends downward on the screen, such that a rectangle's 'top' will have a lower value than its 'bottom'.  If you're using a coordinate system in which positive 'y' extends upward on the screen, you'll need to reverse `<` and `>` comparisons in the pseudocode's top- and bottom-related clauses.

Comment: it wasn't intended to be snark :/ I interpreted the question (and your answer) as the usual "give me AABB overlap calculation codez please". I'll delete my comment now.

Comment: Thank you so much this is so helpful. (It also taught me two words: caveat and psuedocode!)